# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'function'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've seen many questions like this but none seem to be helping me with my issue.
I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'function' recipes: 163` which is pointing on my function startTimer(), see code below.

I dont see anything wrong with my function and I don't know where to look anymore, I've tried everything.

I want my img tag to change src every 3 second, just like a slideshow using js in my ASP.NET MVC project.

```
<div id="image-slideshow" onload="startTimer()">
    <img id="image-changer" src="@Model[0].Image" />
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var index = 0;
        var images = [];

        images[0] = @Model[0].Image;
        images[1] = @Model[1].Image;
        images[2] = @Model[2].Image;
        images[3] = @Model[3].Image;
        images[4] = @Model[4].Image;

        function changePic() {
            document.getElementById("image-changer").src = images[index];
            console.log(index);
            index > 4 ? index = 0 : index++;
        }

        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(changePic(), 3000);
        }
    </script>
}
```

I've tried to pinpoint what this unexpected error means but I cannot see any problems with the function.

Comment: What is `index > 4 ? index = 0 : index++;` supposed to be doing. It doesn't look valid!

Comment: The [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is a expression that returns a value. You shouldn't be attempting to modify `index` like this in place of `if .. else`.

Comment: You probably also want to wrap `@Model[0].Image` with quotes too i.e. `images[0] = '@Model[0].Image';` etc.

Comment: I would suggest rewriting this entire script... but here: `index = index > 4 ? 0 : index + 1`

Comment: @phuzi Thank you! I know understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) expects expressions, not statements.

`index = 0` is a statement.

So if you want to conditionally assign `index`, you have 2 options:

#### Assign using ternary

```js
index = index > 4 ? 0 : index + 1;
```

This works because `0` is an expression and `index + 1` is an expression.

#### Assign using `if`

```js
if (index > 4) {
    index = 0;
} else {
    index++;
}
```